# What is the difference between the two ways we declared a struct?

Tags: c++, syntax

As a beginner with C++ I was learning about linked list and other data structures. After looking at a few implementations online I found these two ways they defined struct. What is the difference between the two. In one we add "struct" before the next pointer, and in one we don't.

Way 1:

```
struct node
{
   int data;
   node *next;
};
```

Way 2:

```
struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: i might be wrong on this but it's only legacy stuff, no difference

Comment: the second is a C-way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
struct node *next;
```

Is only necessary in C code. In C, doing:

```
node *next;
```

Is not allowed. However, in C++, you can use both methods. There is no difference between them in this case.

The only time you would need the `struct` keyword in C++ for a declaration would be if there is some sort of ambiguity or if the `struct` has not been defined yet. (An example for the first would the `stat` function, which is a function *and* a `struct` on POSIX systems).

Comment: About the last paragraph, you are forgetting the most common scenario in my experience, i.e. providing an incomplete definition straight inside a parameter or field declaration. As in `void foo(struct Bar *bar);`, where `Bar` is not actually defined in the header where this declaration is provided. Edit: I see now that this is 2 years old and my use case was already provided in the next answer. Oh well.

Comment: Ok, I was clearly not completely awake :-) I mistook the "Feb 16" for "Feb 2016".

Answer (score 8):

> What is the difference between the two.

The difference is that the latter (called *elaborated type specifier*) declares that `node` is a struct.

In this case, it is redundant to declare that `node` is a struct, because that has already been declared:

```
struct node
^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- node is a struct
{
   int data;
   node *next;
};
```

---

An example of a case where there is a difference:

```
struct a {
    //b* pointer;      // oops, we don't know what b is
    struct b* pointer; // OK, b is a struct
};

struct b{};
```

It is typically<sup>†</sup> not absolutely necessary to use an elaborated type specifier, as it is possible to use a separate declaration instead:

```
struct b;

struct a {
    b* pointer;
};

struct b{};
```

Choice between them is personal preference.

---

<sup>†</sup> I say *typically* because sometimes you need it to disambiguate a variable of same name from a type:

```
int foo;
struct foo{};

int main()
{
    foo = 10;            // refers to int
    struct foo instance; // refers to the struct
}
```

It is usually a bad design to use same name for multiple things, so this is not very typical.

---

Finally, it is sometimes desirable to write header files that can be included in both C and C++. Such header must use the common subset of both languages.

In C, `node` is not a type name, but a *tag* for a structure. It is necessary in C to refer to a struct tag using `struct` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

The second version is required in C, but bad style in C++, and there are almost no situations in C++ in which you actually have to add the keyword like this.

Note that you don't have to write your own linked-list implementations in C++, unless it's for academic learning purposes. Use `std::list` or `std::forward_list`.

Comment: "almost"? Do you have an example where you need the keyword? Nevermind, Arnav Borborah mentions one in his edit. Unless you have another one?

Answer (score 1):

In your case there is no difference at all. However, consider this example:

```
struct foo { struct node* f; };   // <- this is fine
struct foo_broken { node* f; };   // <- wont compile

struct node { };

int main() {
    foo f;
    //foo_broken g;
}
```

Placing the keyword `struct` allows you to declare the member before you declare `node`. Without `struct` the compiler will issue an error (for `foo_broken`):

```
error: ‘node’ does not name a type
```

That is, placing the keyword `struct` acts like a forward declaration. To use `foo` you need to supply a declaration of `node` but it can come after the declaration of `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because C++ grew out of C and C's syntax, and the language kept both types of syntax even though the explicit use of `struct` to declare the type of a variable was no longer needed. There are some cases, i.e., to resolve ambiguity between different types/functions/etc. with the same name, where it would make a difference. Also by keeping this syntax valid in C++, it would help people port C code over to C++ without introducing an error.

In C, by default you had to always place the `struct` keyword in front of the name of the struct. So only Way #2 was valid C:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next; //error in C!
};

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next; //compiles
};
```

But you would often see in C code that `struct` declarations were paired `typedef`s in order to create new types, such as:

```
typedef struct node_t
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

And this would allow `node` to be used as a type without `struct` in front of it. In C++, it effectively automated this `typedef` for all `struct` and `class` types in the code, which is why you can use the `struct` or `class` name without the appropriate qualifier before it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two declarations in C++

Comment: Other answers and comments explain how in certain rare situations, there may be a difference.