# What is the difference between struct Node* and Node* in function call?

Tags: c++, struct, scope, declaration

What is the difference between what is being passed to function1 and function2?

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void function1(struct Node *start)
{
    // ...
}

void function2(Node *start)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: None. What source are you learning C++ from?

Comment: @melpomene not exact. The first one will work if an object named `Node` is in scope, the second one won't compile. The first one will also declare `struct Node` in the outer scope if it has not been declared yet.

Comment: @melpomene There are differences, this is called [Elaborated type specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier)

Comment: "struct Node" is a C-ism. In C++ the "struct" is not needed.

Comment: @Quentin Point, but in the provided code `struct Node` is defined and there are no other objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the difference between the two ways we declared a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831060/what-is-the-difference-between-the-two-ways-we-declared-a-struct/48831154#48831154)

Answer (score 5):

Aside from potentially standing in as a *forward declaration* (a moot point in your case), there is no difference at all. Your using `struct Node*` in the function parameter list is paying homage to requirements in C.

You don't need to do that in C++, since it has a different way of organising its namespaces to C.

For a more formal explanation of the construct, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier

Comment: Lazy copy-paste: not exact. The first one will work if an object named `Node` is in scope, the second one won't compile. The first one will also declare `struct Node` in the outer scope if it has not been declared yet.

Answer (score 5):

The difference essentially, is in what happens when the type wasn't previously declared at the point of the function declaration/definition.

So long as `function1` doesn't try to access any member of the object, it doesn't need the type definition or declaration to be present. It has the effect of introducing a declaration of `struct Node` into the enclosing scope.

`function2` does need it (or a forward declaration somewhere to exist), regardless of what it does with the object. It does not implicitly introduce the class type.

Comment: This is wrong, the second syntax works fine enough with an incomplete type (otherwise we would be seeing `struct Foo`'s everywhere).

Comment: @Quentin This is not really wrong. Without any declaration of `Node`, `function1` works, `function2` doesn't. You're thinking of a `struct Node;` or `typedef struct Node Node;` that isn't present in the question.

Comment: @Quentin - [The second version needs a forward declaration somehwere](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e29156277e62ded)

Comment: @hvd I'm thinking of `struct Node;`. StoryTeller: although I expected that to be what you meant, the type being incomplete has no effect here whatsoever.

Comment: @Quentin - I must say it's quite unlike you to lead with a downvote, though

Comment: My leek is stale and I'm grumpy :(

Comment: @Quentin - *(Sending invisible possible energy across the wire)*. Hope the rest of the day is better for you :)

Comment: Wow this is never seen before

Comment: @Quentin remember that however bad your day is there's someone out there that had to port Microsoft Edge to Android.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: Or porting FORTRAN code to C. Damn 1-based arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The difference can be seen in the following code snippets.

The first one is

```
void function1( struct Node *start );

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

The second one is

```
void function2( Node *start );

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

The first code snippet is well-formed. In the parameter declaration of the function there is used an elaborated type specifier that introduces the type `struct Node`. The structure itself can be defined further after the function declaration.

For the second code snippet the compiler will issue an error because the name `Node` is not defined.

Also the name of the structure can be hiden by a declaration of a variable. In this case you also have to use the elaborated name of the structure.

For example

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int Node;

void function1( struct Node *start );
```

From the C++ Standard (3.4.4 Elaborated type specifiers)

> 2 If the elaborated-type-specifier has no nested-name-specifier, and
>   unless the elaborated-type-specifier appears in a declaration with the
>   following form:

```
class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier ;
```

> the identifier is looked up according to 3.4.1 but ignoring any
>   non-type names that have been declared....If the elaborated-type-specifier is 
>   introduced by the class-key and this lookup does not find a previously
>   declared type-name, or if the elaborated-type-specifier appears in a
>   declaration with the form:

```
class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier ;
```

> the elaborated-type-specifier is a declaration that introduces the
>   class-name as described in 3.3.2