# What is the difference between a struct with a struct type pointer and a struct with a normal pointer?

Tags: c, struct

I don't understand the usage of the word `struct` inside the struct, does it mean it is a pointer to a struct?

```
struct node
{
    int data;     
 
    struct node *left, *right;
};
```

What is the difference between this one above, and this one:

```
typedef struct Node node;

struct node
{
    int data;     
 
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
```

Comment: Each node has a left and right pointer to other nodes. Those pointers are of type `struct node *`, yes. Also, see [What is the difference between struct Node* and Node*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692285/what-is-the-difference-between-struct-node-and-node-in-function-call)

Comment: @gettingAway, `Node *left;` is invalid C code as `Node` is not defined.  Best to post compliable code.

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef Node node;
```

is invalid. It should be

```
//                  alias
//                  vvvv
typedef struct node Node;
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^
//      actual type
```

And that makes `Node` an alias for `struct node`.

Every time `Node` is used it's exactly like writing `struct node`.

So there is no semantic difference between the two structure definitions (provided a valid `Node` alias).

Comment: yeah my bad, i didn't checked my code ;_;. imma edit my question now. So, it means there are no diferences between those two structs? Thanks for answering!

Comment: @gettingAway Still not quite right. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, struct node is a structure that contains an integer member data and two pointers to the same structure type, left and right. These pointers are used to create a binary tree data structure, where each node has a left and right child.

In the second example, typedef Node node; creates an alias for the type Node, so that it can be referred to as node. However, this code is incorrect because Node is not a defined type. The correct way to create an alias for the struct node type would be to use typedef struct node Node;. This would allow you to use Node as an alias for the struct node type.

The difference between the two examples is that in the first example, the structure type is referred to using the struct node syntax, while in the second example, an attempt is made to create an alias for the structure type using typedef. However, as mentioned earlier, the second example is incorrect and would result in a compilation error. To correctly create an alias for the struct node type, you would need to use typedef struct node Node;. This would allow you to use Node as an alias for the struct node type

Comment: yeah, already fixed that, my bad. Thanks for aswering !